# Add a specific tag element after another specific tag element with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the below code:

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#"> 1 </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"> 2 </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#"> 3 </a>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

and i am trying to add after 1st `</li>` the code `<li><a href="#">More</a><ul>` and after the last `</li>` the closing `</ul></li>` with Jquery.

I have tried

```
$( '.menu > ul > li:eq(0)' ).after( '<li><a href="#">More</a><ul>' ); ->tag1
$( '.menu > ul > li:eq(2)' ).after( '</ul></li>' ); ->tag2
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/B86JW/4/

The problem is that `<li>` and `<ul>` is automatically self closing and the same thing for `</li></ul>`

Expected output

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#"> 1 </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">More</a> -> tag 1
      <ul> -> tag 1
        <li>
          <a href="#"> 2 </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#"> 3 </a>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </li> -> tag 2
 </ul> -> tag 2
</div>
```

Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/B86JW/4/

Comment: dom manipulation does not work like a string concatenation

Comment: @ArunPJohny I see, and how can i do this? I know in Vqmod from Opencart i do search and add and i was thinking is quite the same.

Comment: what is the target markup you want to have

Comment: @ArunPJohny I have added the expected output above that i want to have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like this,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/B86JW/6/)

```
    var new_li = $('<li><a href="#">More</a><ul></ul></li>')
    new_li.find('ul').append($( '.menu > ul > li:gt(0)' ));

    $( '.menu > ul > li:eq(0)' ).after( new_li );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var xHtml = $( '.menu > ul > li').first().nextAll().detach();
var xNewUl = $("<li><ul></ul></li>").appendTo('.menu > ul');

xNewUl.find('ul').prepend('<a href="#">More</a>').append(xHtml);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/B86JW/7/)

Updated Version,

```
var xHtml = $( '.menu > ul > li').first().nextAll().detach();
var xNewUl = $("<li><ul></ul></li>").appendTo('.menu > ul');

xNewUl.prepend('<a href="#">More</a>');
xNewUl.find('ul').append(xHtml);
```

### [DEMO I](http://jsfiddle.net/B86JW/8/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too:

```
var html = $('.menu ul li').not(':first').each(function(){
    return this.outerHTML;
});
$( '.menu > ul > li:eq(0)' ).after( '<li><a href="#">More</a><ul></ul></li>' );
$('.menu ul ul').html(html);
```