# Inserting </tr> after First <td> in table using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a structure like below:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class='first'>Some text</td>
    <td class='second'>Some text</td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

What I want to do is add end tr after first **td** so it should be like:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class='first'>Some text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='second'>Some text</td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

I tried

```
$("td.first").after('</tr><tr>') ;
```

but it didn't seem to work.

What are other ways to do this?

Comment: You can't do this. You're not inserting text into text, you're modifying a living DOM. You can't instantiate or insert *backwards* DOM elements like `</tr><tr>`, that isn't a real thing. You need to extract your `<td>` elements, unwrap them, and rewrap them with new `<tr>` elements as you need them.

Comment: [See this link if this helps you.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20046492/1059101)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('.second').each(function () {
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    $(this).wrap('<tr />').parent().insertAfter(parent)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KWT52/)

Comment: This each iterates for one time right? because OP's Dom structure is having only one td with class .second.

Comment: I just designed it to support multiple instances

Comment: This worked fine for me.However I will be having multiple <tr> with same structure.So in that case would this be performance efficient?

Comment: @PrasadW if you don't have 100s of records it should be fine

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var xTd = $("td").detach();

$("table tr").remove();

xTd.each(function(){
    $("<tr></tr>").appendTo("table").append($(this));
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8KPGz/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("td:first").after($("td:last"));
$("tr:last").remove();
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/sRYW7/)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
            tr.append($('.second'));
            $('table').append(tr);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('<tr></tr>').appendTo('table').append('.second');
```